# getting : 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.' with cosmosclient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync method

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, azure-cosmosdb, fluent-docker, cosmosclient

I am trying to run integration test on cosmos db and for that I am using fluentdocker library to use cosmos emulator image (mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator) and run my integration test on it.

With the help of comsosclient object i am creating my instance but when i try to create db with CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync  method I am getting SSl connection couuld not be established issue.

I can see my emulator is running on localhost and I am using its connectionstring to pass it inside cosmos client object while creation.

I even tried with git hub actions way, there also I installed the dummy certificate.but when i try to access it, i am getting the same issue

please help to solve this issue

Comment: Have you considered looking at the 'inner exception'? Have you considered posting it here?